# Using registers in break point conditions with Trace32

Tags: arm, trace32, lauterbach

Trying to set break point at a specific location and set trigger condition that is based on the value of one of the registers e.g. R1 (Cortex-R family CPU).

Is there a way to do it in trace32? What is the syntax for condition?

Comment: Sorry, may you clarify what is meant by a "trigger condition", you mean that "This breakpoint shall stop the execution only if R1 == certain value?"

If that is the case, the only way I see you can do it is setting a breakpoint that launches a Practice scriipt, and that practice script may check the trigger conditions, and thus, resume the execution on the processor (unsing a "go" command) or stop the script execution and releasing control to the user. Please note that this will have a certain impact on code execution time.

Comment: I mean regular program breakpoint with a condition. It is straightforward with conditions that involve static or unoptimized stack variables. It doesn't look obvious why registers in a condition should be any different - so maybe l'm just missing the right syntax to refer to a register? T32 uses 'register.xxx' for manipulating them..haven't seen any construct with a register that can be put to 'watch' window though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also check register values in the condition of a breakpoint.

However, please be aware that conditional breakpoints are always intrusive to the run-time behavior of your chip. That means that your target CPU will always stop at the breakpoint location, then the debuggers evaluates the condition and then restart the CPU, if the condition was not met. (Note, that "conditional breakpoints" are not the same than "data-breakpoints" (certain value written to certain location). Data-breakpoints are non-intrusive on a lot of chips (like your Cortex-R)).

The basic trick is to use the PRACTICE function Register() to access a core-register.

To set a program breakpoint, to stop on a certain program location and stay stopped, if a core-register contains a certain value, use one of the following commands:

- `Break.Set <prog.addr|symbol> /Program /CONDition Register(<reg.>)==<reg.value>`
- `Break.Set <prog.addr|symbol> /Program /VarCONDition \Register(<reg.>)==<value>`

E.g.:

- `Break.Set P:0x1000 /Program /CONDition Register(R0)==0x42`
- `Break.Set P:0x1000 /Program /VarCONDition \Register(R0)==0x42`

The difference between the two commands? The first one uses TRACE32 expressions, where symbols stand for their address (like the linker sees symbols). The second one uses so-called HLL expressions, where symbols stand for variables like in the C/C++ language. (HLL expr. == C-style expr.)

Usually it is easier to write conditions in HLL expressions (especially when they deal with variables), while using PRACTICE functions is usually easier in TRACE32 expressions.

You can also set the condition in the Break.Set dialog: Click on the button "advanced" and then your condition in the field "CONDition". The HLL checkbox on the right of the field "CONDition" defines if your using a HLL expression or not.